# How to set center position for google maps

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-visualization

Tweeked the below code but couldn't set the center position in the below code. I found several tips but unfortunately I couldn't implement them into my code successfully.

Can someone help?

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    google.load('visualization', '1.1', {
      packages: ['map']
    });
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawMap);

    function drawMap() {
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('string', 'Address');
      data.addColumn('string', 'Location');
      data.addColumn('string', 'Marker'),

        data.addRows([
          ['London, England', 'TouristMagnet', 'london'],
          ['Paris, France', 'TouristMagnet', 'paris'],
          ['Dubai, United Arab Emirates', 'TouristMagnet', 'dubai'],
          ['Istanbul, Turkey', 'TouristMagnet', 'istanbul'],
          ['Barcelona, Spain', 'TouristMagnet', 'barcelona'],
          ['Amsterdam, Netherlands', 'TouristMagnet', 'amsterdam'],
          ['Milan, Italy', 'TouristMagnet', 'milan'],
          ['Rome, Italy', 'TouristMagnet', 'rome'],
          ['Vienna, Austria', 'TouristMagnet', 'vienna'],
          ['Prague, Czech Republic', 'TouristMagnet', 'prague'],
          ['Athens, Greece', 'TouristMagnet', 'athens'],
          ['Moscow, Russia', 'TouristMagnet', 'moscow'],
          ['Berlin, Germany', 'TouristMagnet', 'berlin'],
          ['Sofia, Bulgaria', 'TouristMagnet', 'sofia'],
          ['Budapest, Hungary', 'TouristMagnet', 'budapest'],
          ['Sydney, Australia', 'TouristMagnet', 'sydney'],
          ['Venice, Italy', 'TouristMagnet', 'venice']
        ]);
      var url = 'http://dfsm9194vna0o.cloudfront.net/';

      var options = {
        zoomLevel: 5,
        showTip: false,
        useMapTypeControl: true,
        icons: {
          london: {
            normal: url + '1401895-0-london100.png',
            selected: url + '1401898-0-london200.png'
          },
          paris: {
            normal: url + '1401894-0-paris100.png',
            selected: url + '1401897-0-paris200.png'
          },
          dubai: {
            normal: url + '1401892-0-dubai100.png',
            selected: url + '1401893-0-dubai200.png'
          },
          istanbul: {
            normal: url + '1401890-0-istanbul100.png',
            selected: url + '1401891-0-istanbul200.png'
          },
          barcelona: {
            normal: url + '1401886-0-barcelona100.png',
            selected: url + '1401888-0-barcelona200.png'
          },
          amsterdam: {
            normal: url + '1401883-0-amsterdam100.png',
            selected: url + '1401885-0-amsterdam200.png'
          },
          milan: {
            normal: url + '1401881-0-milan100.png',
            selected: url + '1401882-0-milan200.png'
          },
          rome: {
            normal: url + '1401876-0-rome100.png',
            selected: url + '1401877-0-rome200.png'
          },
          vienna: {
            normal: url + '1401874-0-vienna100.png',
            selected: url + '1401875-0-vienna200.png'
          },
          prague: {
            normal: url + '1401872-0-prague100.png',
            selected: url + '1401873-0-prague200.png'
          },
          athens: {
            normal: url + '1401870-0-athens100.png',
            selected: url + '1401871-0-athens200.png'
          },
          moscow: {
            normal: url + '1401868-0-moscow100.png',
            selected: url + '1401869-0-moscow200.png'
          },
          berlin: {
            normal: url + '1401866-0-berlin100.png',
            selected: url + '1401867-0-berlin200.png'
          },
          sofia: {
            normal: url + '1401864-0-sofia100.png',
            selected: url + '1401865-0-sofia200.png'
          },
          budapest: {
            normal: url + '1401860-0-budapest100.png',
            selected: url + '1401863-0-budapest200.png'
          },
          sydney: {
            normal: url + '1401858-0-sydney100.png',
            selected: url + '1401859-0-sydney200.png'
          },
          venice: {
            normal: url + '1401852-0-venice100.png',
            selected: url + '1401855-0-venice200.png'
          }
        }
      };
      var map = new google.visualization.Map(document.getElementById('map_div'));

      map.draw(data, options);
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map_div" style="height: 600px; width: 1000px"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You dont draw a `google.maps.Map` , it's a [`google.visualization.Map`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/map) which doesn't implement a method to set the center.

By  default it's centered in the middle of the rows(locations).

You may only center it based on the rows.

When you e.g. want to center it at the location of a particular row you must select the row programmatically via [`setSelection`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#vissetselection).

Example for Dubai(the 3rd row  in your dataset, so the rowIndex is 2)

```js
google.load('visualization', '1.1', {
      packages: ['map']
    });
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawMap);

    function drawMap() {
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('string', 'Address');
      data.addColumn('string', 'Location');
      data.addColumn('string', 'Marker'),
      //removed some rows to speed it up
        data.addRows([
          ['London, England', 'TouristMagnet', 'london'],
          ['Paris, France', 'TouristMagnet', 'paris'],
          ['Dubai, United Arab Emirates', 'TouristMagnet', 'dubai'],
          ['Istanbul, Turkey', 'TouristMagnet', 'istanbul'],
          ['Barcelona, Spain', 'TouristMagnet', 'barcelona'],
          ['Amsterdam, Netherlands', 'TouristMagnet', 'amsterdam']
        ]);
      var url = 'http://dfsm9194vna0o.cloudfront.net/';

      var options = {
        zoomLevel: 5,
        showTip: false,
        useMapTypeControl: true,
        icons: {
          london: {
            normal: url + '1401895-0-london100.png',
            selected: url + '1401898-0-london200.png'
          },
          paris: {
            normal: url + '1401894-0-paris100.png',
            selected: url + '1401897-0-paris200.png'
          },
          dubai: {
            normal: url + '1401892-0-dubai100.png',
            selected: url + '1401893-0-dubai200.png'
          },
          istanbul: {
            normal: url + '1401890-0-istanbul100.png',
            selected: url + '1401891-0-istanbul200.png'
          },
          barcelona: {
            normal: url + '1401886-0-barcelona100.png',
            selected: url + '1401888-0-barcelona200.png'
          },
          amsterdam: {
            normal: url + '1401883-0-amsterdam100.png',
            selected: url + '1401885-0-amsterdam200.png'
          },
          milan: {
            normal: url + '1401881-0-milan100.png',
            selected: url + '1401882-0-milan200.png'
          },
          rome: {
            normal: url + '1401876-0-rome100.png',
            selected: url + '1401877-0-rome200.png'
          },
          vienna: {
            normal: url + '1401874-0-vienna100.png',
            selected: url + '1401875-0-vienna200.png'
          },
          prague: {
            normal: url + '1401872-0-prague100.png',
            selected: url + '1401873-0-prague200.png'
          },
          athens: {
            normal: url + '1401870-0-athens100.png',
            selected: url + '1401871-0-athens200.png'
          },
          moscow: {
            normal: url + '1401868-0-moscow100.png',
            selected: url + '1401869-0-moscow200.png'
          },
          berlin: {
            normal: url + '1401866-0-berlin100.png',
            selected: url + '1401867-0-berlin200.png'
          },
          sofia: {
            normal: url + '1401864-0-sofia100.png',
            selected: url + '1401865-0-sofia200.png'
          },
          budapest: {
            normal: url + '1401860-0-budapest100.png',
            selected: url + '1401863-0-budapest200.png'
          },
          sydney: {
            normal: url + '1401858-0-sydney100.png',
            selected: url + '1401859-0-sydney200.png'
          },
          venice: {
            normal: url + '1401852-0-venice100.png',
            selected: url + '1401855-0-venice200.png'
          }
        }
      };
      var map = new google.visualization.Map(document.getElementById('map_div'));
      google.visualization.events.addOneTimeListener(map, 'ready', function(){ 
        map.setSelection([{row:2, column:null}]);
        map.setSelection(null);
      });
      map.draw(data, options);
    }
```

```css
html,body,#map_div{height:100%;margin:0;padding:0;}
```

```html
<div id="map_div" ></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works perfectly!

Comment: Could please tell me where you found such documentation?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/map#methods